How to set up a storage space all flash tiering in powershell?
I have two very fast, write intensive NVMe SSDs, and many slower SATA SSDs. Using Windows Server 2019 (but happy to upgrade to 2022 if it helps).
What I want to do is to build a virtual disk with two tiers, one fast mirror tier with the NVMe SSD, and one slower parity (~RAID5) tier with the SATA SSDs (so slower because of SATA, but also the poor parity performance in storage space).
Problem: when I define a tier in Powershell, I can only specify the mediatype which is SSD for both, and I don't seem to be able to specify which individual drive goes in which tier. I don't seem to be able to query the tiers after the fact to find which disk has been allocated to which tier either.
Is there a syntax to do that, and is it even possible to create an all flash tiered storage space?
